# Vertex/node attributes for igraph objects

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with network analysis data in igraph 
Here is an example dataframe

```
df_edgelist=structure(list(Nominator = structure(c(6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L), .Label = c("Andrea", "Dan", "Dan", "Greg", "Jerry", 
"Jim", "Rachel", "Sarah"), class = "factor"), Nominee = structure(c(5L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("Andrea", "Dan", "Greg", 
"Jeff", "Jerry", "Jerry", "Sarah", "Tim"), class = "factor"), 
    Age_Nominator = c(24L, 25L, 29L, 45L, 43L, 67L, 67L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

From the documentation [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html) I get the impression that the `graph_from_dataframe` function will treat that 3rd column `Age_Nominator` as a vertex attribute if I also supply it with another dataframe and set the name of that dataframe in the `vertices` argument of `graph_from_dataframe`. Is that correct or is that 3rd column in `df_edgelist` still an edge attribute?

Comment: The variable `Age_Nominator` has values corresponding to edges. For instance in the first row of your data.frame does 24 apply to Jim or Jerry? Igraph will by default load this as an edge attribute. If you want it as a vertex attribute you need to create a data.frame where each named vertex corresponds to an attribute value.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense but wasn't sure because the documentation was a little confusing. So when I load in the vertex attribute dataframe Does it matter if the dataframe I load in has extra names that aren't included in a sepcific edgelist? I'm working with multiple different edgelists, but have one dataframe with attributes for all vertices in every edgelist and would like to just use that dataframe instead of splitting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two arguments of interest in `graph_from_data_frame` are `d` and `vertices`. As discussed in the comments, extra columns in `d` will be edge attributes, while extra columns in `vertices` (with the first columns being vertex names) will be vertex attributes.

Further,

> If `vertices` is not `NULL` then the symbolic edge list given in `d` is checked to contain only vertex names listed in `vertices`.

means that the first two columns of `d` cannot mention any vertices that are not present in `vertices`. On the other hand, if `vertices` has some extra vertices, that will raise no issue and they will simply be isolated.

For instance,

```
df_vertices <- data.frame(someNames = c("NewName", as.character(unique(unlist(df_edgelist[, 1:2])))))
df_vertices$Age <- 20 + 1:nrow(df_vertices)
df_vertices
#    someNames Age
# 1    NewName  21
# 2        Jim  22
# 3       Greg  23
# 4     Rachel  24
# 5      Sarah  25
# 6     Andrea  26
# 7        Dan  27
# 8      Jerry  28
# 9        Tim  29
# 10      Jeff  30
```

in this way we consider all the necessary vertices and add an extra `NewName`. Then

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df_edgelist, vertices = df_vertices)
# V(g)$Age
#  [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
V(g)$name
#  [1] "NewName" "Jim"     "Greg"    "Rachel"  "Sarah"   "Andrea"  "Dan"     "Jerry"   "Tim"    
# [10] "Jeff"   
E(g)
# + 8/8 edges from 7f024f1 (vertex names):
# [1] Jim   ->Jerry  Greg  ->Dan    Rachel->Tim    Sarah ->Andrea Andrea->Sarah  Dan   ->Greg  
# [7] Dan   ->Jerry  Jerry ->Jeff
```

as expected. In case you want to avoid those isolated vertices, as `vertices` you may instead specify

```
df_vertices[df_vertices$someNames %in% as.character(unique(unlist(df_edgelist[, 1:2]))), ]
#    someNames Age
# 2        Jim  22
# 3       Greg  23
# 4     Rachel  24
# 5      Sarah  25
# 6     Andrea  26
# 7        Dan  27
# 8      Jerry  28
# 9        Tim  29
# 10      Jeff  30
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870651/r-language-understanding-what-is-a-weighted-graph

Comment: Is it possible to add node weights in igraph? Can graph clustering algorithms make use of node weights (instead of edge weights)?