# igraph vertex attributes graph_from_data_frame best practices

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, network-analysis

I am working with igraph in R with a huge network and I am a bit afraid of messing the df up. I followed [Vertex/node attributes for igraph objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741257/vertex-node-attributes-for-igraph-objects) and read R-igraph tutorials and docs.

Yet, I am missing something suppose I have this data:

```
toy_data = data.table(source = c(1,1,1,3,5,5,1,1,1,3,5,5), 
                      source_name=c(Milan,Milan,Milan,Frankfurt,London,London,Milan,Milan,Milan,Frankfurt,London,London), 
                      from=c("A","A","A","C","E","E","A","A","A","C","E","E"),
                      target=c(2,3,1,4,6,5,5,1,1,1,3,NA), target_name=c(Paris,3,1,4,6,5,5,1,1,1,3,NA),
                      to=c("B","C","A","D","F","E","E","A","A","A","C",NA))
edges <- toy_data[,.(source,target)]
v <- data.frame(labels=as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(source,target)]))),
                names = as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(source_name,target_name)]))),
                category = as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(from,to)]))))
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices = v, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph,vertex.label=v$names,vertex.color=c("pink","skyblue")[1+(V(graph)$category=="A")])
```

All good as long as the "unique" vectors unlisted have the same length, but to me it doesn't seem a very good practice to individually load vertex attributes as separate columns since it is enough to have one duplicate (here from and to fields have "A" for Frankfurt instead of "C") that the vectors are not equal-sized any longer:

```
toy_data = data.table(source = c(1,1,1,3,5,5,1,1,1,3,5,5), 
           source_name= c("Milan","Milan","Milan","Frankfurt","London","London","Milan","Milan","Milan","Frankfurt","London","London"), 
           from=c("A","A","A","A","E","E","A","A","A","A","E","E"), 
           target=c(2,3,1,4,6,5,5,1,1,1,3,NA), 
           target_name=c("Paris","Frankfurt","Milan","Dublin","Madrid","London","London","Milan","Milan","Milan","Frankfurt",NA),
           to=c("B","A","A","D","F","E","E","A","A","A","A",NA))
toy_data
edges <- toy_data[,.(source,target)]
v <- data.frame(labels=as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(source,target)]))),
                names = as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(source_name,target_name)]))),
                category = as.character(unique(unlist(toy_data[,.(from,to)]))))
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices = v, directed = FALSE)
plot(graph,vertex.label=v$names,vertex.color=c("pink","skyblue")[1+(V(graph)$category=="A")])
```

So if I have a data.table structured already in this way how could I tell `igraph` to bind the node id to some features? (sort of zip() function in python?)

Comment: In case you're wondering how you should do... What I did: changed the source dataframe to have a edge file with only two columns and a vertices dataframe with the set of unique nodes with all their characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Word of caution, still trying to figure out igraph myself. However, it looks like the Source and Target fields can be renamed to common attributes. Similar to creating an edges table, you can create a vertices table with unique ids and attributes. Then can use `set_vertex_attr` on the graph.

Also, noticed that `NA` is listed as a node, and not handled. Consider handling that otherwise, igraph will throw errors.

```
library(igraph)
library(data.table)

# using toy_data input from post
edges <- toy_data[,.(source,target)]

#setnames to rename the source and target columns to common attribute names
#rbind to union together
#unique to get unique nodes with attributes
v <- unique(rbind(setnames(toy_data[,.(source,source_name,from)],c("labels", "names", "category")), 
      setnames(toy_data[,.(target,target_name,to)], c("labels", "names", "category"))))

#can now add features to the data table
v[,color:= ifelse(category == "A", "pink", "skyblue")]

graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, vertices = v, directed = FALSE)

#set_[vertex|edge]_attr to set node and edge attributes with columns
graph <- set_vertex_attr(graph, "label", value = v$names) 
graph <- set_vertex_attr(graph, "color", value = v$color) 

plot(graph)
```

[image: graph of data]